# Fantasy story about a boy, a gem, a dwarf and a djinn

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a story I read as a kid. I only remember very little, but the fantastic results in other questions makes me hope you can find the answer.

Here is as much as I can remember:

- It is a fantasy book, or possibly multiple books
- I am pretty sure it is directed to young readers
- I read it in German
- I read it probably some time between 1995 and 2000
- The protagonist is a boy who might have been called Michael (or Micha, or Mischa)
- I think he has a gem (maybe a dark gem), I think on a necklace, which allows him to change from the "real world" to a fantasy world
- I remember that he is accompanied in the fantasy world by a male, hairy dwarf, who is quick with words, and some kind of djinn or ghost or spirit
- I think in one occurence (maybe right at the beginning), he crossed over to the fantasy world from the back of his school yard
- I remember one occurence where the boy was carried around by a big tree, sitting in the branches - much like Merry and Pippin being
  carried around by Treebeard in Lord of the Rings, but I think the
  tree was travelling through a swamp, and I am not sure if the tree
  was sentinent like treebeard was.

  - That part - being carried by the tree - might also have been part of the cover of the book.

Comment: In English, a dschinn is a djinn (e.g. a genie)

Comment: True, but the book was read in German. If it was a German book that hasn't been translated into English, you'd have more luck searching for _Dschinn_ instead, I think

Comment: To be fair, I don't even know if it was described using the word "Djinn" (Or Dschinn, for that matter)... I remember picturing it being similar as the final boss in the Wario Land Gameboy game...

Comment: I can only think of "Bartimaeus"- Sequence, or Bartimäus in German. Could that be it?

Comment: That does not look like it (even though it looks interesting). The Djinn in my story was good, and also other parts do not add up. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 3):

Could this be The Talisman by Stephen King and Peter Straub? It deals with a crystal and crossing over between two worlds.

Comment: Unfortunately not... good find though :)